# In SQL database, how to populate a field in table with path to folder?

Tags: database, ms-access, field

Created a folder on the server called InstrumentOutputFiles, with three sub folders.  Output files from a lab machine will be stored in these folders.  The developed database is in 2010 Access and interfaces with a defined set of folders on the server.

The list of these folder paths are in a form called frmACBusUnit. I am supposed to add a new field to the table tblBusUnit with a script to create InstrumentOutputs varchar(200) which I think I've done with

```
--  tblBusUnit Add InstrumentOutputs column
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'tblBusUnit' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'InstrumentOutputs'))
ALTER TABLE tblBusUnit 
ADD InstrumentOutputs nvarchar(200) NULL
```

Then I will have to populate the new field with a path to the folder and then add the new InstrumentsOutputs field to frmACBusUnit.

My question is how do I populate a field with a path to a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some way of identifying the correct row, such as a primary key Id, but it looks something like this:

```
UPDATE tblBusUnit SET InstrumentOutputs = 'YourFolderPath' WHERE MyIdField = Id
```

This works pretty much how it reads: it will set the value of the column InstrumentOutputs equal to whatever you put inside the quotes, but only on rows that match the criteria provided.

Be a bit careful doing updates if you're not sure how they work. You might want to backup your database first, and work with that until you're confident of what you're doing. Then back it up again before trying on the live data.